# Livekit proxing traffic from one room to another

Tags: go, sdk, webrtc, rtp

I use golang sdk for Livekit.
My case:
I have one room with some tracks. And i have another room where located one user(subscriber). So, i would like to make mechanism to correct proxing tracks from one room to another. How i can do it? Someone do simmilar case with go and Livekit.
Thanks for any answers

I try to subscribe on this event OnTrackSubscribed, but i have freeze and big delays, i think when i do it by this way the standart webrtc mechanism of synchronization doesn't work.